# Why is my query not being updateable stopping me updating a table with it?

Tags: ms-access

I've trying to update a table using the following UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE tblPlayers_atp INNER JOIN qryMostRecentScoresOv _
& ON tblPlayers_atp.ID = qryMostRecentScoresOv.ID _
& SET tblPlayers_atp.ELO_Ov = [qryMostRecentScoresOv].[ID_nEloOv];
```

When I hit run I get "Operation must use an updateable query". The source query `qryMostRecentScoresOv` includes GROUP BY which I gather is the issue.

Now I've read quite a bit around this but what I don't understand is why this causes an issue? The action I'm performing doesn't update the query in any way - it just wants to use the data within it. I realise this might be a basic question but I've been reading for a while now and couldn't find the answer.

If it helps here is the SQL for the source query:

```
SELECT tt.ID, tt.ID_nEloOv
FROM qryUniScoresEloInc AS tt INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(PK_G) _
& AS [Max] FROM qryUniScoresEloInc WHERE ID_nEloOv is not null _
& GROUP BY ID)  AS groupedtt ON (tt.ID = groupedtt.ID) _
& AND (tt.PK_G = groupedtt.Max)
ORDER BY tt.ID;
```

I'm now setting about creating a temporary table from the source query and update from that... https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately, in Access, the query becomes not updateable in any case if any of subqueries contains aggregation or even DISTINCT.

Comment: And a non-updatable query cannot be used directly in an UPDATE action. Just the way it is. Could use VBA to loop through query and use its data to run multiple UPDATE actions. So approach with temp table is probably fastest. But why save aggregate data to table? If you can retrieve calculated data in aggregate query, there is usually no need to save it.

Comment: If your aggregate query introduces any ambiguity to the join or your tables are missing primary keys, your query will not be updateable.